# Flyway naming suggestion

Tags: flyway

I want to use the same version name but a different description with each SQL file to use the description part identifier so each SQL file will be different from the others. I want to check if new SQL scripts are in the history table if not execute them rather than the flyway default bigger version name approach.

Is this can be done or the version names must be different no matter what.

Comment: Why do you need for the version numbers to be the same for different files? If they are the same, Flyway doesn't know what order to execute them in.

Comment: To further customize its validation mechanism and my own personal education.

Comment: I don't understand "to further customize its validation mechanism"